# Eigenvalues Problem with eigenvalue variable substitution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have the following eigenvalues problem ($a,\ b,\ c,\ d,\ x,\ y$ are known values, with $x \neq y$):

$$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
a-\alpha x& b \\
c & d-\alpha y
\end{array} \right| = 0$$

so I thought it was possible to solve it like this:

$$\left| \begin{array}{cc}
a-\lambda& b \\
c & d-\lambda
\end{array} \right| = 0$$

And at the end I could do this:

$$ \lambda_1 = \alpha_1 \ x $$
$$ \lambda_2 = \alpha_2 \ y $$

Is this correct?

**PS**: I tried it with some values and it worked. But at first it seems that it doesn't make much sense. And as I was trying to find some kind of answer to this I arrived at this expression:
$$\lambda^2-\lambda(a+d) = \alpha^2 x y - \alpha(ay+dx)$$
$$\Leftrightarrow \ \  \frac{\lambda}{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha xy-(ay+dx)}{\lambda-(a+d)}$$
If I could get rid of the $a$ and $d$ it would be great.

Comment: Why? Why not just write down the equation for $\alpha$ from your original determinant (which is a quadratic equation in $\alpha$) and use the quadratic formula?

Comment: I was trying to "speed up" some calculations and minimize the numeric error.

I didn't actually calculate the propagation of the error. Mainly it's to improve some calculations that  I have to do by hand.

Comment: Is this in the context of numerical computations? If so please use the [tag:numerical-linear-algebra] tag.

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just a theoretical question.

But eventually it will be used on numerical problems.

Comment: In any case, if you multiple your original matrix by the diagonal matrix diag(1/x,1/y), you end up with a standard eigenvalue problem with $\alpha$ being the eigenvalue. Would that be good enough? // I am pretty sure the solution scheme that you wrote down is wrong.

Comment: This is what I did: $(a-\alpha x)(d-\alpha y) - cd = 0 \Leftrightarrow \alpha^2 xy-\alpha (ay+dx) - cb = 0$

Comment: Did the same with $\lambda$ and, as they both are equal to zero, put one equal to the other

Comment: I don't mean your algebra. I mean the entire idea that at the beginning. See answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach cannot be correct.

1. The original determinant equation leads to a quadratic in $\alpha$, so there are two solutions. The eigenvalue equation leads to a quadratic in $\lambda$, so there are two solutions. If $x \neq y$ and $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$ and $\alpha_1 \neq \alpha_2$: there is no good reason why $\alpha_1$ should be paired with $x$ and not with $y$. (In other words, to get from $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ to $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ as you suggested by dividing by $x$ and $y$, the solutions you get depend on a choice on how to pair the values $x,y$ with the values $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$, so the scheme cannot possibly be correct.
2. In the case $x = y$, you can just divide the entire matrix by $x$, and you will have that indeed $\lambda = x \alpha$ gives you a scaling of the solutions. But this is not true in general.

   Remember that one interpretation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors, in the case $b = c$, is that the eigenvectors allow you to simultaneous diagonalize two symmetric matrices, one being $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and the other being the identity. Turns out your first equation is the generalization where you try to simultaneously diagonalize the matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$ and $\mathrm{diag}(x,y)$. The relation between the two problems are *complicated* geometrically, and you can't really expect a good way to map solutions of one to the other.
3. Explicit counterexample: let $a = b = c = 1$, $d = 2$, $x = \frac13$, and $y = 1$. Then you find
   $$ \lambda = \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{5}}{2} $$
   and
   $$ \alpha = \frac{5 \pm \sqrt{13}}{2} $$
   For your approach to hold $\lambda$ and $\alpha$ must be rationally related, which they are not.

Comment: Thank you! It was an excellent explanation !